# Passing data from table view cell to tab view controller child via segue

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to figure out how to pass data from a tapped tableview cell into a child view controller in a tab bar view controller. This is what I currently have:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?){

    if segue.identifier == "edit" {

        let cell = sender as! UITableViewCell
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)
        let roomController : RoomViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! RoomViewController
        let room : Rooms = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as! Rooms

        roomController.room = room

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your attempt seems correct, what exactly is not working?

Comment: The data from the table view is not transferring to one of the children of my tab view

Comment: Is the child view controller `roomController`? That's the only view controller you've passed the data to unless there's more code that you're not showing.

Comment: Yes, sorry I wasn't more clear, but roomController is the child view controller.